# Filtering individual dates in R, dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a large dataset with about 60 years of data, and I'm trying to make daily calculations to the water level column in the dataset which contains daily water levels at different locations. To do this, I think I need to filter out each date individually, which is very time-consuming. Is there a faster way to do this? I thought about writing a function, but even with this, I would still have to type in the individual dates (I think?).

Here is the head and tail of my data:

`X      Date             Water.Level..cm.       Lat      Long
1      1      1977-11-01               NA -12.80861 -48.24028
2      2      1977-11-02               NA -12.80861 -48.24028
3      3      1977-11-03               NA -12.80861 -48.24028
4      4      1977-11-04               NA -12.80861 -48.24028
5      5      1977-11-05               NA -12.80861 -48.24028
6      6      1977-11-06               NA -12.80861 -48.24028
350719 350719 1938-01-26              635 -5.533333 -47.48333
350720 350720 1938-01-27              667 -5.533333 -47.48333
350721 350721 1938-01-28              710 -5.533333 -47.48333
350722 350722 1938-01-29              717 -5.533333 -47.48333
350723 350723 1938-01-30              721 -5.533333 -47.48333
350724 350724 1938-01-31              690 -5.533333 -47.48333`

And this is what I currently have:
`nov1 <- dat %>% filter(Date == as.Date("1989-11-01"))`

I would like to end up with different data frames containing all of the data in master data frame for each date:

`X       Date      Water.Level..cm.       Lat      Long
1  4384 1989-11-01              711 -12.80861 -48.24028
2 10684 1989-11-01               NA -12.47056 -48.21139
3 10929 1989-11-01              240 -12.44722 -48.26806
4 15373 1989-11-01              275 -12.35500 -48.25889
5 37414 1989-11-01              246 -12.30444 -48.26222
6 51326 1989-11-01              240 -12.26194 -48.32917`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want different data frames containing all of the information in the master data frame for each individual date, you could use the split() function.

```
df_list <- split(dat, as.factor(dat$Date))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use `group_by()` and `summarise()`

You're looking for a way to summarise your data by a factor, in this case `Date`.

```
data %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(mean = mean(Water.Level..cm.))
```

This returns a table of grouped summaries. See [this link](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-summaries-with-summarise) for more information.

Comment: I need to preserve all of the individual data points for each day so I can run an interpolation on them, so having 1 mean point for each date wouldn't work.

Comment: You can preserve the individual data points by using `mutate` instead of `summarize`.

Comment: @thatsciencegal, that makes sense. I wasn't exactly clear what you meant. In that case, using `split` like @jalind suggests is the way to go. Then you can `lapply(df_list, function(x) {interpolate(x)})`. =)